# How to add text on screen using bitmapfont in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I have a function class that implements `Screen` with a `bitmapFont` variable in it
`BitmapFont f=new BitmapFont();`

In the render function of this class, I am trying to print the health of players t1 and t2.

```
    String s= "Player 1 Health\n"+t1.getHealth();
    game.getBatch().begin();
    // game.getBatch().draw("some other sprites)
    f.setColor(1.0f,1f,1f,1f);
    f.draw(game.getBatch(),s,300,1400);
    s= "Player 2 Health\n"+t2.getHealth();
    f.draw(game.getBatch(),s,1300,1400);
    game.getBatch().end()
```

However I am not able to see any output on my screeen.
Please tell how to solve this one.

Comment: Check background color first and set coords to `0,0`

Comment: @КириллНовгородцев I am afraid I don't know how to set coordinates. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: `f.draw(game.getBatch(),s,1300,1400);` <- 1300, 1400 change to `0,0`

Comment: @КириллНовгородцев I tried it but it still does not seem to work.

Comment: I am not sure why but it started working when i removed the '\n' from the string. If someone has an explanation regarding why this happened then please let everyone else know.

Comment: I cannot confirm this, because I don't repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

```
        FreeTypeFontGenerator fontGenerator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font file"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter fontParameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

        fontParameter.size = 14;
        fontParameter.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);

        BitmapFont font = fontGenerator.generateFont(fontParameter);
        font.draw(batch, "START GAME!", 0f, 0f + font.getCapHeight());
```